# how to show one more array in the tooltip using highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I am going chart in my project.and i am used for that high chart. and i am getting success for the show chart dynamically.and i have 3 array. 1st array store Dates.2nd array store Followers count, and 3rd array store string. so i want 3rd array in the tooltip. right now in the tooltip show just followers count now i want to also show 3rd array data. so how can do that any idea about this then please tell me. here below i have listed my code with screen shot any one know then please help me.

This is my array =>

```
var Dates = [];
"11-10-2017"
"12-10-2017"
"13-10-2017"
"14-10-2017"
"15-10-2017"
"16-10-2017"
"17-10-2017" 

var FollowersCount = [];
  "0"
  "0"
  "0"
  "0"
  "50"
  "10"
  "0"

 var Activites = [];
  ""
  ""
  ""
  ""
  "Comment,LIke"
  "Like"
  "0"
```

i want to show this 3rd array in the just tooltip.

This is my code =>

```
*Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: Dates
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        sourceWidth: 400,
        sourceHeight: 300,
        scale: 1,
        buttons: {
            customButton: {
                text: 'Next Dates',
                onclick: function () {
                    alert('You pressed the button!');
                }
            },
            anotherButton: {
                text: 'Previous Dates',
                onclick: function () {
                    alert('You pressed another button!');
                }
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: "Followers"
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Followers',
        data: FollowersCount 
    }
    ]
});*
```

This is my Chart Screen shot =>

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is by adding the extra data to each point, in your case, adding activies to each datapoint. And then displaying them in the tooltip with a formatter. I have made an example:

First make a new array containing both your value and the activity:

```
var processedData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < FollowersCount.length; i++) {
  processedData.push({
    y: FollowersCount[i],
    activity: Activites[i]
  })
}
```

Set that as your data:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Followers',
  data: processedData
}]
```

Then create a tooltip to display this activity, but only if it is present:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    let tmpTooltip = '<b>' + this.point.category + '</b><br/><span style="color:' + this.point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + this.series.name + ': <b>' + this.point.y + '</b>';
    if (this.point.activity != "") {
      return tmpTooltip + '<br/><b>Activity:</b>' + this.point.activity;
    } else {
      return tmpTooltip;
    }
  }
}
```

In the end you have a graph that looks like this:
[image: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/cujmdg85/2/]

**Working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/cujmdg85/2/

**API on tooltip formatter**: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Awesome i want same like this but now date it's hide in the tool tip and Before Activity Small blue color in the Dot how can put that do you know??

Comment: @Edit I have updated the code now to match this comment. If you want to move the blue dot, then just move the `span` element to wherever you want it in the formatter.

Comment: Thanks i will do with your code and tell you thank you so much

Comment: It's Amzing answer thank you so much for your helping.